# Packaging commercial application

Tags: application-development

I'm developing a project tracking application that I intend to release not far in the future as a commercial (for purchase) app in the software center. I'm just trying to figure out how to best package it for submission, but the description for this is vague at best:

Is there a straightforward packaging guide for commercial software?

(No compilation, just stuff my folder into the `/opt/appname` directory on install).

Comment: I've deleted the two other questions, as they should be separate question posts. Feel free to post two other question posts. You can view the old version of this question post by clicking the date next to "edited".

Comment: In case you're participating in the "MyApps" programme, there's this page linked in the first steps: [Uploading your app - Commercial and proprietary software](http://developer.ubuntu.com/publish/my-apps-packages/) and there in the section below you'll find the differences applying to general Debian packaging guidelines. If this provides an answer, I could put it like one.

Answer (score 0):

I you are submitting it as a for-purchase app, you will get packaging assistance from Canonical staff.  Just submit what you have through the MyApps portal, even if it's just a tarball, and that will get you started.